# Using `git gui` with `git submodules foreach`

Tags: git, git-bash

I have a git repository with a number of submodules that are very similar. This means that any change which is done to one of them is typically done in similar way to the other submodules.

Therefore a common task is to do the changes and then create all the commits.
For adding changes and creating the commit I prefer to do a `git gui &`.

Now I would like to open the gui for all submodules at once.
For other commands I simply use `git submodule foreach 'git status'` or similar.
But if I try to use `git submodule foreach 'git gui &'` the command finishes rather quickly and after that I get dialog windows for each submodule popping up that indicate that folder `.git` directory is not found.

I assumed this might be due to asynchronous execution of `git gui &` but if I remove the `&` it fails in the same way. Only the command exits after first submodule.

I am using git bash of [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) under Win10.